# Error in datatype of image (System.InvalidCastException)

Tags: c#, mysql

[An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe and Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW5X5.png)

How can I fix this? I can't view my saved query with image in mysql using c#. I used blob datatype in saving image in mysql. And I'm a college student, we are having IT Project now in school.

**This is my code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string connStr = "server = 127.0.0.1; uid = root; " + "pwd =; database = dbSample";
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
            MySqlCommand cmd;
            MySqlDataAdapter da;
            string query = "select * from image where name = '" + txtFirstname.Text + "' ";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
            da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dt);

            txtFirstname.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            byte[] ImageData = (byte[])dt.Rows[0][1];       // <----this is the error.
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ImageData);
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

            da.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the right column

$byte[] ImageData = (byte[])dt.Rows[0][1]);

Look
 "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'."

This mean Your selected Column is string type that cannot be converted to Byte..

Comment: thanks sir :) sorry for wasting your time, I'm just a beginner at programming. What should I put in there? I don't have yet an idea in adding images and retrieving it in view windows form. TIA. :)

Comment: [Try this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8ea152/fetch-image-from-database-in-windows-form-application/)   :)